# How can I count the number of cycles in a column with cyclic values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'c': [1,2,1,2,3,2,3], 'b': [5,6,4,5,5,6,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
```

and I want to create the column `N` with the cycle number of `c`:

```
   b  c  N
0  5  1  1
1  6  2  1
2  4  1  2
3  5  2  2
4  5  3  2
5  6  2  3
6  4  3  3
```

How can I do that?

Comment: how do you define 'cycle'?

Comment: It may not be appropriate to call it 'cycle', but the values in column N indicate it.

Comment: that's my whole point, I don't understand what N should be and I'm asking for clarification

Comment: so you want to know when the v of c is less than its previous value?

Comment: I think a more accurate description might be, "I want to label continuously increasing sequences"

Comment: Examples, while very helpful, can still be ambiguous.  For example, say you have [1, 2, 2].  Does the second 2 start a new cycle (because it's not greater than the previous value) or not (because it's not less than the previous value)?  Etc.

Comment: The first 'cycle' starts from a small value and increases until reaching the maximum, the second 'cycle' starts from a lower value than the previous one to another maximum, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`shift`** to see if **`c`** stops increasing:

```
(df.c < df.c.shift()).cumsum().add(1)

0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
Name: c, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `diff` and `cumsum`

```
(df.c.diff() <0).cumsum()

0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
```

If need, add 1

```
(df.c.diff() <0).cumsum() + 1
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
```